# How to check an IF statement every 5sec in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a `li` and inside that i have a `div class="reload"` that have some content that should be reloaded for every 10 sec.

```
<li class="b1">                    
    <div class="reload">
    </div>
</li><!--col-->
```

So therefore i have got a script that does just that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.b1').children('.reload').load('php/reload/reload.php'); // load the content at start

window.setInterval(function(e) {
$('.b1').children('.reload').load('php/reload/reload.php'); // reload the content every 10 sec
}, 10000);
```

In the reload.php i get some content from a database. It looks like this, sort of..

```
<?php 
  // login info
  require("../../connection_to_database_login.php"); 
  // My query
  $result = mysqli_query($l,'SELECT * FROM abcd WHERE efg=1 LIMIT 1');
  // include some stuff
  $r = mysqli_fetch_row($result);for ($p = 0; $p < $r[4]; ++$p){include("../some/stuff_$p.php");};

  // include a random picture script or just load a picture
  if ($r[4] == 0){include ('getRandPic.php');} 
  else {echo ('<img src="images/picture.png" />');} 
  ?>
```

So far so good.. everything works.

The **getRandPic.php** file.. select one random picture from a folder

```
  <?php
  $img_dir = "images/images";
  $images = scandir($img_dir);
  $html = array();
  foreach($images as $img) {
    if($img === '.' || $img === '..') {continue;} 
      if (  (preg_match('/.jpg/',$img))  ||  (preg_match('/.gif/',$img)) || (preg_match('/.tiff/',$img)) || (preg_match('/.png/',$img)) ) {             
        $html[] .= '<img class="img-responsive" src="'.$img_dir.$img.'" />'; 
      } 
      else { continue; }    
  }; 
  echo $html[rand(0,6)];
?>
```

So this works ok.

But the thing is, i want to check if it shall **"include a random picture script or just load a picture"** every 5sec.

Therefore i need to check `"if ($r[4] == 0)"`  every 5 sec.

**So my question is:** Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: This is not the answer **BUT** You have too many DB queries and calls to server. Why not to read all image names in one call, store it in javascript array or something and then every 5 second change the source randomly ?

Comment: You cannot check something every n seconds in PHP unless you call the script every n seconds. I suspect that the mechanism here is not optimised for what you are trying to do. What exactly are you trying to achieve, and why?

Comment: i am verry new to this and everything i know is from reading stuff on internet. So if you can give some examples how to do that it would be greatfull @Nis

Comment: if you read i think you can imagine what i am trying to do... get a picture based on the if statement an if i get one make it random.. but keep checking if there shall be a picture @FMC

Comment: @user3341623 , as you asked please check my answer. It is a rough guide only. You will have to develop and write your own code based on this guide.

Comment: this will make you code more unoptimised. I have a suggestion. If you want to pull the random pic. I believe the source file name will be different. So you can get all the image URL put it as as JSON. once you have a JSON object you can change it how ever you wanted I mean you can set an interval `<img src="+ imgURL +" />` this way it would be easy for you access.

Answer (score 1):

**As you asked in the comment... This is a rough guide only. You will have to develop and write your own code based on this guide.**

**Step 1a:** *optional*

Make an ajax call from your webpage to the server. to get image file names.

**Step 1b:**

On server side in php file perform DB operation. 
Let assume you have a table `imageTable` and column name `images` so you would read from DB using query `SELECT images FROM imageTable`

You will have to change the query, add condition (e.g. all images with animal and cute tags) to it and if you want limit the number of files that you want to randomize then you will have to add that as well.

**Step 2:**

Once you read from DB, as you are already doing, read all image names and put it in `json` format ([json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)). I personally prefer json. If you prefer, you can also return all names in simple string where names are separated by comma.

**Step 3:**

Store your response in JS.

```
var imagesArray = new Array();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: pathtophpfile,
        success: function(htmll) {
                            // get object with all data
            imagesArray= JSON.parse(htmll);
        },
    });
```

**Step 4:**

Once you have it in your js object named `imagesArray`, use [setInetval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) to perform task every 5 seconds.
Read a random value from 0 to `imagesArray`s length, and change the source of your image tag,  `<img class="img-responsive" src="+ randomimage +" />`

Comment: thank you for the example @Nis :) my code is the pictures that are in my FOLDER and all of the file-names are at the moment imported and converted into a array in getRandPic.php No file names is stored in my database. I wanted it to be simple... just take all pic in the folder and no need to have any naming convention. and geting the images is just one call at the moment.. i think.

Comment: Glad i could help. **BTW**, I m new to this site as well but if the answer has helped you, you should accept it so that it helps other people with similar problem. It also increases overall acceptance % for site.

Comment: yes it has helped me to lower the amount of calls to the database. But it was not the answer to the main question so i cant make it a accepted answer, sry.

Comment: after further use of your @Nis code, i know realize that if i use your way i will have to move the image outside of the reload div. otherwise it will reset the piture on reload and the timing will be of. But by doing so i go back to may original question "how to check the if statement" because moving it outside will make it not chcking if the pic shuld be there. every 10 sec.

Comment: Well I only answered this from the perspective of reducing the calls to server to get images ( and to purely answer your comment).. BTW, on what basis are you deciding whether to _"include a random picture script or just load a picture"_? Can you please explain in plain english? **If** it is on the basis of some change in DB then it is better to use some sort of push service like http://www.pubnub.com/how-it-works/

Comment: hi again @Nis, sry for not answering earlier but i have been on veccation :) Yes it is based on a change in the DB. Advert or other picture that is related to the content.

Answer (score 0):

Periodic updater will do your task. 
Use ajax framework, it will reduce your db connection burden at the server side. 
Have a look at it. It is a simple and nice way to achieve your task.

http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/ajax/Ajax/PeriodicalUpdater/

Comment: I don't think he has mentioned that he is using Prototype.js framework. And if he is a newbie, then as far as i know he will have tough time managing Prototype and jQuery both together !